# JQuery Lightbox moves up/down when image is changed

Tags: jquery, css

Guys wanna ask if **how can i make the lightbox popup to stay still (not moving up and down) when i clicked next/prev button.**. I would like to use css only if possible

It looks like the image below:
[image]

I used the latest Wordpress Jquery Lightbox(Latest version plugin)

The site is available in: `http://204.197.252.143/~themainr/`

One of the links(underlined) in the homepage will open the a jquery popup box as shown like the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightbox is processing the image size to exactly center it on your screen.

So, make the images exactly the same size (at least the height) ?

Here you have 646x378, 641x367 and 663x353